# How to generate test with playwright and codegen from a docker container?

Tags: docker, playwright, codegen

I'm using their standard image mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.1-focal.
When trying to launch the command `yarn playwright codegen wikipedia.org` from my docker container (for the sake of an example) I'm getting the following error:

```
Looks like you launched a headed browser without having a XServer running.                     
Set either 'headless: true' or use 'xvfb-run <your-playwright-app>' before running Playwright.
```

I don't want to run it as headless cause I wan't to generate tests.
Not sure how to setup an Xserver for my purpose, and the doc doesn't seem to mention this issue.

Any help appreciated

Comment: hey, hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/75271849/3153739

Answer (score 0):

Use `Xvfb` inside container.

You can use `xvfb-run` to start `playwright codegen`, then use `x11vnc` to start a vnc server, so you can use vnc viewer on your host machine to control it.